# Improper JSON serialization from Unity (arrays and wrapper being used)

Tags: arrays, json, unity-game-engine

While I could serialize/deserialize simple data with JsonUtility, when trying to load an array of objects into my game, Unity didn't respond well.

I do understand that the utility doesn't take arrays, so alternative solutions are needed.
I've tried using the wrapper posted [here](http://www.boxheadproductions.com.au/deserializing-top-level-arrays-in-json-with-unity/) (Thanks!!), but it's still not doing what I'd expect it to do.

While I'm passing all the details into the JSON, when saving it, it's only saving instanceIDs, which are not very useful for persistency.

Here's the step by step.

### **1. Creating the object**

```
private Customer[] _customerDeck;

Customer yidler = new GameObject().AddComponent<Customer>();

    yidler.race = GameController.Race.Alien;
    yidler.initial = true;
    yidler.patience = 3;
    yidler.dice = new ResourceGroup();
    yidler.dice.diceRequired = 1;
    yidler.dice.resources = new Dictionary<GameController.Resource, int>();
    yidler.dice.resources.Add(GameController.Resource.Food, 3);
    yidler.dice.resources.Add(GameController.Resource.Beverage, 0);
    yidler.dice.resources.Add(GameController.Resource.Dessert, 1);
    yidler.moneyAwarded = 6;
    yidler.fidelityAwarded = 1;
    yidler.starsAwarded = 0;
    yidler.initial = true;
    _customerDeck[0] = yidler;

    JSONManager.SaveCustomers(_customerDeck);
```

### **2. Saving the JSON**

```
public static void SaveCustomers(Customer[] customers)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, customerCardsFile);

    if(File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        string data = JsonHelper.ToJson<Customer>(customers);
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);
    }
    else
    {
        Supporting.Log("Cannot find Customers JSON", 1);
    }
}

public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
        return wrapper.Items;
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array)
    {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T>
    {
        public T[] Items;
    }
}
```

### **3. Additional Info**

- The Customer class is System.Serializable, same as the ResourceGroup referenced within it.
- This is the resulting json

  {"Items":[{"instanceID":-47734},{"instanceID":0},{"instanceID":0},{"instanceID":0},{"instanceID":0}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all try remove `MonoBehaviour` inheritance from `Customer` class. Also Unity's default serializer doesn't support `Dictionary<>` serialization. Try to change from Dictionary to a List of Serializable class. Also check that all inner Customer data fields are serializable too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The key aspect was the inheritance from Monobehaviour. But the JSON Utility seem too limited at this point. Upon further testing, I'd need to not only change the Dictionary, but also the enums I'm using (those didn't get Serialized either). I may give a shot to the XMLSerializer instead, before refactoring the code just to support the JSON.

Comment: @TalyHotimsky enums can be serialized. Mark them as [Serializable] and this will work. But in json you'll see int from enum and after desirializing everything will be ok.

Comment: That's good to know! One less thing to change up!